# R Atomic Vectors, how do access elements

Tags: vector, atomic

I probably have a basic question, but this is the first time I've really gotten to grips with atomic vectors. I loaded data from a state file and placed into a data frame. Looks something like this:

```
$ hv202   : atomic  13 13 43 13 13 13 13 13 42 21 ...
 ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "source of non-drinking water"
 ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%8.0g"
 ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num  10 11 12 13 20 21 30 31 32 40 ...
 .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "piped water" "piped into dwelling" "piped to yard/plot" "public tap/standpipe" ...
```

I want to get the labels and names out of there. This is a Stata construct which has numeric values for variables and then character labels for their meaning.

How can I pull out the value - attr(*, "labels") part and the - attr(*, "labels") so I can use tools like dplyr's recode or if I just want to know the value and label of the ith element of the vector?